# Determine the div that contains the product price on different product pages

Tags: html, css, algorithm, probability

I'm looking for a general method of defining the product price containing div when only the HTML and CSS source code is provided. On Amazon for example, the product price is always contained in a div with a specific class (same for all products, leave for some edge cases). Same is true for Ebay, except that the div has a different class.

A few general patterns that can be noticed: 
- The div that contains the product price contains a dollar sign followed by a number
- The text-size of the div is bigger than the other divs fitting the above pattern
- Color of the text might be different in the main price div.

Is there an efficient way to do this, that is applicable to pretty much any page? Would it be best to just go with a bayesian network and pick the div that has the highest probability of containing the product price based on the above patterns??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things that can help are :-

> 1. css classes,font style,font size,color to price div are generally similar for same website.
> 2. As you mentioned there is similar id for all pages in same website.
> 3. There might be dollar or rupees symbol in vicinity of the value.
> 4. Moreover a nearby div or parent div might have words like " price cost.." etc.

You can construct a bayesian network for each website which takes note of all the above features and evaluates the probability of the div being the price. Give your network some positive examples of each website and evaluate the network values.

Use tools like [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) for html parsing for extracting divs.